# Google open id profile picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, profile

How do i retrive a users profile-picture when using googles open id?

Comment: Does this answer: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_photo

Comment: Great! Exactly what I'm looking for!